# How to implement SMTP and IMAP in Node.js

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, imap

Node.js has built-in implementation for http protocol using the module system which aids in creating web servers.

Does it have anything similar for the smtp and imap protocols of the e-mail?

I already know that I can use modules such as nodemailer and whatever, but I want to learn how to do it myself and I really don't mind to reinvent the wheel as some might be pointing, but I have the curiosity to learn. Just want to know the technique I can use to do so with nodejs and its core modules.

I don't mind linking to other sources that can help (a note that can be ignored).

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `smtp-server` (npm)  also known as  `nodemailer` module to create a smtp server

for docs, refer this [link](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/)

Comment: and I said that I already know that nodemailer exists and I want to know how email protocols are implemented in plain nodejs not npm modules

Comment: He is asking for implementation.